# How to update HTC desire 630 to Android 7 without rooting the phone?

Tags: updates, htc-desire, 7.0-nougat, htc

I would like to update my HTC desire 630 to Android 7 without rooting it. I currently have 6.0.1 installed.

Have anyone done it? Are there any good articles? I found [this one](http://nougatmyandroid.com/android-nougat-7-0-update-htc-desire-630/), not sure if to try it out.

Comment: Pointers: Our [updates tag-wiki](/tags/updates/info) and especially, linked from there, [How do I update the OS on my device?](/q/13510/16575)

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't, just because HTC does't support it anymore.

Comment: can you clarify - doesn't support what? Android 7?

Comment: The term of HTC 630 is final. If you want upgrade to Android 7, you need unlock bootloader by yourself, then find the cook roms and flash it